# React setState object in array and map result

Tags: reactjs

Currently I am so far that I can display a selected value of the dropdown in a variable by setState. But this is with 1 value. I would like to place an object in setState to display it later. The current code works, until I select the 'Treatment' dropdown, after which the app crashes.

What I would like is that if that is selected as a dropdown, it will be displayed in the . Is there a way for that?

The current code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import styles from "assets/jss/material-dashboard-react/views/dashboardStyle.js";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Close from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import { render } from "react-dom";

const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);


export default function ChaskDesk() {

  const employee = ["Robin","Raoul","Joppe "];

  const service = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Knippen',
        price: 10.00

    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Scheren',
        price: 10.00
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Wassen',
        price: 10.00

  }]
  const counting = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
  const gender = ["man", "vrouw", "kind"];
  const client = ["Passant"];

  const [employeeOrder, setEmployeeOrder] = useState('');
  const [serviceOrder, setServiceOrder] = useState([]);
  //const serviceOrder = [];
  const countingOrder = [];
  const genderOrder = [];
  const clientOrder = "";

  const payment = 0;
  const classes = useStyles();

    const handelChangeGender = function(event){
        genderOrder.push(event.target.value);
        console.log(genderOrder);
    };

    const handelChangeService = function(event){
        for(var i = 0; i < service.length; i++) {
            if (service[i].id == event.target.value) {

                setServiceOrder(service[i]);
                console.log(serviceOrder);
            }
        }

    };

    const handelChangeEmployee = function(event) {
        setEmployeeOrder(event.target.value)
      }




  return (
    <div>
      <Container className={classes.containerPixelActive}>
          <h3>Afrekenen</h3>
          <Row className={classes.tablePixelRow}>
            <Col md={8} className={classes.rowChashdesk}>
            <form>
            <Row>
                    <Col md={6}>
                    <label>
                        Klant:
                    </label>
                    <br/>
                    <select >
                        {
                            client.map(function(item, i){
                                return <option key={i} value={item}>{item}</option>
                            }) 
                        }
                    </select>
                    </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                    <Col md={6}>
                <div className={classes.rowOfForm}>
                    <label>
                        Gender:
                    </label>
                    <br/>
                    <select onChange={handelChangeGender}>
                        {
                            gender.map(function(item, i){
                                return <option key={i} value={item}>{item}</option>
                            }) 
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
                </Col>
            </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col md={6}>
                    <div className={classes.rowOfForm}>
                        <label>
                            Behandeling:
                        </label>
                        <br/>
                        <select onChange={handelChangeService}>
                        {

                            service.map(function(item, i){
                                console.log(item);
                            return <option key={i} value={i}>{item.name}</option>
                            }) 
                        }
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={6}>
                    <div className={classes.rowOfForm}>
                        <label>
                            Medewerker:
                        </label>
                        <br/>
                        <select onChange={handelChangeEmployee}>
                        {
                            employee.map(function(item, i){
                                return <option key={i} value={item}>{item}</option>
                            }) 
                        }
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                {
                            serviceOrder.map(function(item, i){
               return <Row key={i} >
                    <Col md={6}>
                    <div className={classes.rowOfForm}>
                        <label>
                            Verkregen behandeling:
                        </label>
                        <br/>

                            <input type="text" name="name" value={item.name}/>

                    </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={2}>
                    <div className={classes.rowOfForm}>
                        <label>
                            Aantal:
                        </label>
                        <br/>
                        <select>
                        {
                            counting.map(function(item, i){
                                return <option key={i} value={item}>{item}</option>
                            }) 
                        }
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={2}>
                    <div className={classes.rowOfForm}>
                        <label>
                            Prijs:
                        </label>
                        <br/>
                            <input type="text" name="name" />
                    </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={2}>
                    <div className={classes.rowIcon}>
                        <Close size={20} ></Close>
                    </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            })}
            </form>
            </Col>

            <Col md={3} className={classes.rowChashdesk}>
                <h5>Totaal overzicht</h5>
                <h6>Medewerker</h6>
                <p>{employeeOrder}</p>
                <h6>Behandeling</h6>

                <h6>Aantal</h6>
                <p>{countingOrder}</p>
                <h6>Klant</h6>
                <p>{clientOrder}</p>
                <h6>Te betalen</h6>
                <p>{payment}</p>
            </Col>

          </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );

}
```

The error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is that the `id` values in your `service` array are 1, 2, and 3, and the `value`s of the dropdown options are 0, 1, and 2 (the array indices). So when you select option 0, it can't find a service with that `id` and crashes.

A much simpler way to do it would be to make the `value` in the dropdown options be the whole service object, and then set state using that:

```
<select onChange={handelChangeService}>
    {
        service.map(function(item){
               console.log(item);
               return <option key={item.id} value={item}>{item.name}</option>
        }) 
    }
</select>
```

and for `handleChangeService`:

```
const handelChangeService = function(event){
    setServiceOrder(event.target.value); // this will be the service object
};
```

This makes your code much simpler - you don't need to go searching for the right object with a `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but if I change the code to this version I get another error message "TypeError: serviceOrder.map is not a function", do you have a solution for that? I am adding a screenshot to the question above.

Comment: It's very difficult to tell what your code is trying to do, because I don't speak good German, so without understanding the intent of the code I can't really help. It looks like you're trying to set `serviceOrder` to be an object (in `handelChangeService()`) but later on you're treating it like an array (by calling `.map()` against it). Without knowing more about the purpose of the code I can't figure out which one you really want!